# Sorting Array returns a Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following object:

```
private var datasource: [Int: [MyCustomModel]] = [:]
```

At a later stage, I need to sort the `datasource` by the `key` property (ascending).

I do it as follows:

```
let sorted = datasource.sorted(by: {$0.key < $1.key})
```

This does sort the content by the `key` (Int) value perfectly, though I cannot set the `datasource` to the `sorted` property.

Xcode presents the following error

> Cannot assign value of type '[Dictionary<Int, [MyCustomModel]>.Element]' (aka 'Array<(key: Int, value: Array)>') to type '[Int : [MyCustomModel]]'

I get that the returned type, after sorting is a Dictionary and not an Array.
How can I overcome this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: "though I cannot set the datasource to the sorted property" You should be able to, unless what you have shown is not your real code. If `sorted` is of type `[Int : [MyCustomModel]]`, why not make it a `[(key: Int, value: Array)]` instead? Dictionaries are _just_ not sorted, and you can't change that.

Comment: You want to just sort by key and want result in [Int: [MyCustomModel]]. Right?

Comment: Your *object* is a dictionary, not an array. Dictionaries are unordered by definition. If you are going to sort a dictionary you get an array of tuples.

Comment: @JigneshMayani Exactly. Sorting by key

Comment: @Sweeper I'll try the change you've mentioned and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get any solution for the same to sort the dictionary, but you can do something like below.

Its works for me.

make structure of key and value.

```
struct STRUCT_TEMP
{
    var key : Int
    var value : [MyCustomModel]
}
```

create structure variable.

```
var structTemp : [STRUCT_TEMP] = []
```

convert your dictionary in structure like below:

```
self.structTemp = datasource.map({ STRUCT_TEMP(key: $0.key, value: $0.value) })
```

now you can do anything with the structTemp array. Like sorting, filter and you can also use this array everywhere you want instead of dictionary.

Comment: ohh, this might actually work. I'll try this out.

Comment: @IvanCantarino Okay, and let me know if you got any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

```
let datasource: [Int: [MyCustomModel]] = [:]
```

**Dictionaries cannot be sorted!**. If you use `sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key})` to sort the `datasource`, the result is an array, not a dictionary.

```
datasource.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key})
```

---

## Swift 5.5

You can use  `OrderedDictionary`. It keeps insertion order.

https://www.advancedswift.com/ordereddictionary/